# Added a Shape (AddFormControl=xlButtonControl) to an embedded Chart. No Shape added to Chart Shapes collection

Tags: excel, vba, shapes

I have to add some shapes to an embedded chart in a worksheet...

no problem with text box

````
Set Sh = Ch.Shapes.AddTextbox(Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
       Left:=left, Top:=top, Width:=width, Height:=height) 
Sh.name = "txtName"```
````

Apparently no problem with controlbutton

```
Set Sh = Ch.Shapes.AddFormControl(xlButtonControl, Left:=Ch.Left + left, _
          Top:=Ch.Top + top, Width:=width, Height:=height) 
Sh.name = "btnName"
```

even if I had to offset the Shape's Left and Top properties value with the respective Chart's properties value in order to move the shape in the right position (first strange thing!!!)

With the code included into a different routine I have to delete these shapes.
While I have no problems with textbox

```
Set Sh = Ch.Shapes("txtName")
Sh.Delete
```

I can't do the same thing when I try to delete the controlbutton

```
Set Sh = Ch.Shapes("btnName")
Sh.Delete
```

During troubleshooting, I found out that, while a new shape is added to the `Ch.Shapes` collection after using the `Ch.AddTextbox` method, no new shape is added to the same collection after using the `Ch.AddFormControl` method. I'm sure enough this is the reason why I can't delete the controlbutton while I can do it for textbox.

Does anybody of you know how to help me? It sounds really strange

Comment: Hmmm - seems like the form control is tied to the worksheet shapes collection, not the chart.

Comment: The button is not "in" the chart - if you move the chart the button does not move with it.  That would explain why you had to offset the Top and Left Properties.

Comment: @BigBen Even if I do explicitely Ch.Shapes.AddFormControl(xlButtonControl) and I would expect the button into the chart shapes collection, the shape is not there but it is not into the worksheet shapes collection either. I found that button into the worksheet Buttons collection. It sounds as a bug!!

Comment: It should be in the `Worksheet.Shapes` collection (tested and was so for me). It would also be a member of the `Buttons` collection too, yeah. But to @TimWilliams's point, the button is not actually in the chart...

Comment: @Tim Williams Yes, that's exactly how it is. Is there a way to do what I want?

Comment: If you need something that acts like a button then you can add a rectangle shape, set its text etc and set the "onaction" property to whatever sub you want to trigger from it.

Comment: @BigBen You are right... the button shape is into the worksheet shapes collection too